# Submit button not centering

Tags: php, html, css, web

I have an HTML form and I have all the inputs except for the submit button in a table. I centered everything in the table besides except for the submit button, even though I tried numerous things to center it to no avail. Please help me center my submit button under my table with the other inputs!

Here is my HTML page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Site.css">
    <?php include("Header.php"); ?>
    </div>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
        <h1>About</h1>

        <form action="Insert.php" method="post">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>First name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Last name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Age:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="age"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <?php include("Footer.php");?>
    </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;
background-color: #4C875E;
color: #C9C9C9;
}

#main {
padding: 20px;
background-color: #1C404A;
border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
}

h1 {
border-bottom: 3px solid #4C875E;
color: #4C875E;
}

#swag {
left: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
margin-top: -100px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
width: 100%;
border-bottom: 0;
text-align: center;
color: #BABABA;
}

ul#menu {
padding: 0;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
}

ul#menu li {
display: inline;
}

ul#menu li a {
background-color: #1C404A;
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 2.8em;
color: #C9C9C9;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
background-color: #e8eef4;
}

#bg {
background: url(assets/banner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: 100% auto;
}

table {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it inside your table:

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>First name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Last name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Age:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="age"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan='2'><center><input type="submit"></center></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kimbarcelona01/nQuwL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <tr>
    <td><input type="submit"></td>
 </tr>    
</table>
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7s96r/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <center><input type="submit"></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BQcn7/1/)

You should put the input button inside the table in a new row
Use `td colspan` to merge 2 columns
 To center the button, use attribute `align="center"`.

**Code**

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>First name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="firstname"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Last name:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="lastname"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><span>Age:</span></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="age"/></td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit"/></td>
              </tr>    
                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no exact way to center things in CSS with a single command. However there are some ways that you can do it manually. I would do one of two things. First (forgive me if this seems too simple) I might just add something like & nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp;& nbsp; in front of the submit button. So that would just add some space in front of it (and it scales pretty nicely if the user zooms in).

The other thing I would do (and probably the better solution) would be to change the width of the parent div (so that it is just wide enough to fit the form) and then get the width of that like so:

```
parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('main')).width)
```

divide it by two to get the center, then place the button at the center minus half the width of the button:

```
parseInt(getComputedStyle(getElementById("mySubmitButtonId")).width)
```

Note: place it using margin-left